# Writing a Regular Expression

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write one regular express to search for a phone number similar to 
`011 (134) 1234567892`.

The country code must only be 011. And the area code in () can be 134 132 131 138 136 or 137. The last 10 numbers can be random. I have this

`((\<011[\-\. ])?(\(|\<)\d\d\d[\)\.\-/]?)?\<\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\>`

but it is only giving me one result.

If any could please give me some help..that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what language you are using. To match all results you should add g flag to your re. How to add it is language-dependent, though. Generally `//g` is enough for regular expression literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work:

```
(011 \(13[124678]\) \d{10})
```

You can see working [**DEMO**](http://regexr.com?36qqo) which shows couple of correct and incorrect inputs.

Comment: This will also match on things like 5011 (131) 1234567892, althought only 011 (131) 1234567892 will be matched. OP might want to use `\b` to only match on word boundaries or something. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
^011 \(13[124678]\) \d{10}$
```

seems to match all of the phone numbers I tried given your constraints

`^` matches the start of string

`011` matches *only* 011

`\(13[124678]\)` matches 134 132 131 138 136 or 137

`\d{10}` matches a digit using the digit character class exactly 10 times using the repeat N syntax `{n}`

Answer (score 0):

`/011 \(13[124678]\) \d{10}/g`

Don't forget the `g` flag to match all the occurrences.